# using third column as a label for the segment range

Tags: graphics, gnuplot

I have a plain text file that has N amount of segments in this format :

```
#SegmentX  SegmentY  SegmentRangeX
   100        100
   300        100         200
```

Where SegmentRangeX represents (x2-x1)

I need to  plot this for N amount of Segments, With a label next to each segment showing me the SegmentRangeX, how do i fetch the value for the label ?

Comment: That is a quite common question https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+Column+label+%5Bgnuplot%5D, like https://stackoverflow.com/q/20624270/2604213

Comment: @Christoph You are right, i did not search well enough, and when i found an answer, it did not work inside my loop. But thanks to your links, i got what i wanted, cheers !

Comment: Good, indeed quite often, when I search for duplicates using words from the title of the new questions, I don't find anything. This time I found  one, so don't worry :)

Comment: @Christoph yeah i always need to remember to use the most generic words that describe my topic, then narrow it down to more specific ones in case i don’t find anything related to my question. Thanks again tho, you saved me from hours of surfing the web ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Christoph i found exactly what i wanted

```
'' index i using 1:2:3 with labels offset 2 title ''
```